A small error in the FAQ
There appears to be a small error in the main site's FAQ:
a cryptocurrency or technology derived directly from Bitcoin such as [Namecoin][2]

The [Namecoin][2] should be a link, but it is just a plain text.

Thanks. Copy-paste mistake. Fixed now.
